# Escape characters in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have this code in jsp :

```
<%
out.println("<a href='final.jsp?itemId=<%=item.id%>'>"+id[i]+"</a>" );//here
%>
```

But the problem is I want to pass arguments to another page using this:

```
<a href='final.jsp?itemId=<%=item.id%>'>
```

But this is inside quotes and as soon as I insert second % (**item.id%>**)it take it as a jsp symbol instead I want it inside quotes as normal characters? What should I do?

Comment: Actually, it seems you're closing the href before adding the id[i]. Shouldn't be after it?

Comment: no,id[i] is the link so , it should be outside anchor tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
out.println("<a href='final.jsp?itemId=" + item.id + "'>" + id[i] + "</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
out.println("<a href='final.jsp?itemId=&lt;%=item.id%&gt;'>"+id[i]+"</a>" );
```